# Splitting a string through other ways

Tags: java, string

I have a string, "004-034556", that I want to split into two strings:

```
string1 = "004"
string2 = "034556"
```

That means the first string will contain the characters before '-', and the second string will contain the characters after '-'. I also want to check if the string has '-' in it. If not, I will throw an exception. How can I do this?

Now one way to achieve this is ...

```
public static String[] SplitUsingTokenizer(String Subject, String Delimiters) 
{
    StringTokenizer StrTkn = new StringTokenizer(Subject, Delimiters);
    ArrayList<String> ArrLis = new ArrayList<String>(Subject.length());
    while(StrTkn.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        ArrLis.add(StrTkn.nextToken());
    }
    return ArrLis.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) is a legacy class. If you read its docs, it clearly asks you to use the `split()` method of `String` class. A simple `str.split("-")` would work for you.

Comment: I suggest using variable names with lowercase first letter.  
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
String str  = "004-034556";

if (str.contains("-")) { // Check if str contains "-"
    String strSplit[] = str.split("-");
}
else {
    // Throw exception
}
```

`strSplit[0]`==> 004

`strSplit[1]` ==> 034556

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String[] spilited = abc.split("-");
if(spilited.size() == 0){
    throw new RuntimeException("String doesn't contain '-');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] array = givenString.split("-");
```

and to check it,

```
if(givenString.contains("-")) return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SplitException extends Exception{
    ...
    ...
}

public String[] customSplit(String str, String splitter) {

    String[] splitted = str.split(splitter);
    if (splitted.size() == 0)
        throw new SplitException();
    return splitted;
}

try {
    customSplit("004-034556", "-");
}
catch(SplitException se) {
    se.printStackTrace();
}
```